# How do I center a bullet point on a screen?

Tags: html

When I use the `<center>` tag along with the `<ul>` tag in my html code, The bullet points are staying on the left while the text is appearing in the center. How do I fix this?

here is the problematic code:

```
<center>
<h2>future projects</h2>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Weird dreams</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</center>
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but none of it has worked.

Comment: why have you tagged this question as python?

Comment: Do not use the [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tag. You should use CSS `text-align: center` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> <center> is Deprecated in HTML4 onwards. So, it can be replaced using CSS as:
> ```

```
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <h2>future projects</h2>
      <div>
        <ul style="list-style-position: inside;">
          <li>Weird dreams</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Use list-style-position to center the unordered list bullets.

```
<center>
<h2>future projects</h2>
  <div>
    <ul style="list-style-position: inside;">
      <li>Weird dreams</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</center>
```

[image]

Comment: keep in mint that the center tag is deprecated !!! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 0):

set style as `list-style-position: inside;` for "ul"

Comment: check the below Answer

Answer (score 0):

The center tag is deprecated.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center
Use style-sheet instead...
Like here :

```css
        #center{
            text-align: center;
        }
        #center ul{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="center">
        <h2>future projects</h2>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>Parrot</li>
              <li>stiff</li>
              <li>Pining for the flords</li>
              <li>resting</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </div>
```